# Joomla issue - "$this->items = $this->get('Items'); does not work anymore under PHP 7.1 and 7.2

Tags: php7

In my component I am assigning the data from the model to the view using

```
class FileUploaderViewFileUploader extends JViewLegacy  
{  
    // Overwriting JView display method  
    function display($tpl = null)   
    {  
        // Assign data to the view  
        $this->items = $this->get('Items'); // => This causes the error    
        // Display the view  
        parent::display($tpl);  
    }  
}
```

The error at my website I get is:

```
Error: 0  
Using $this when not in object context
```

Anybody an idea what happened here? This code worked well under PHP 5.6.x as well as PHP 7.0.26.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: For Joomla on php7+ you have to turn on debug to see the line numbers of the fatal error in the stacktrace.  I don't think the line you point to is throwing the error.

Comment: I should also add for clarity that for Joomla on php7+ you can only write fatal errors to the error log when you have debug on (though usually I find the stack trace number is fine). By 'debug' I mean set 'Yes' in Administration > Global Configuration > System > Debug System.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. I called `JSite` in my model.

I changed it to:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$menu = $app->getMenu();
```

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is coming from that line? If so, you may want to review your model's getItems method (include it also in your question for review). Likely you might be calling a static method somewhere, where you can't use `$this`.

Also, what is your Joomla version - is it up-to-date? Have you just updated Joomla? Are you sure the update went smoothly? Note that this error might be coming from anywhere... e.g. a plugin, or core code if an update didn't completed successfully.

Enable error reporting and debug and see what else information you get from there.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. So the Joomla version is up to date at 3.8.3. I enabled the error reporting and the debug mode, but the system fails and do not show the console at that time. :-(

Comment: Found the issue. I called JSite in my model. I changed it to:

`$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();`

which fixed the issue. Thank you all.

Comment: @AndreasIsele please post your solution as an answer and award your answer the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved by the system.  Thank you for your effort.